# pacemakerのリソース移動時にバランシングされない設定について

Tags: linux, centos

環境
■ CentOS7.2 x2台（それぞれA,Bという名前）

上記環境にてpacemakerでクラスターを構築しております。
オプションなどはいっさい設定しておりません。

この場合、Aサーバーに存在しているリソース１つをBサーバーへ移動させると、Bのサーバーにあった他のリソース1つがAに移動してきてしまいます。
（リソースの数のバランスをとるかのような動き）

Aサーバーのリソースを一度全部Bサーバーへ移動させて、Aサーバーのリソース状況を空っぽにしたいのですが、上記のような動きのため一生かかっても空っぽにできません。

pacemakerのオプションでリソースを移動しても、バランスをとらないというなオプションをご存知のかたいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけませんでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。
足りない情報等ございましたら追記させていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resource-stickiness` に値を設定するといいと思います。

```
(例)
pcs resource defaults resource-stickiness=INFINITY
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かりました。